# AOSP repo sync error on jsoncpp but git clone is OK

Tags: git, android-source, repo

I am trying to clone newest AOSP (tag  android-p-preview-4) back.
However, I always met the following error:

```
Fetching project platform/external/jsoncpp
Fetching projects: 100% (637/637), done.
Syncing work tree:  37% (236/637)  error: failed to unpack compressed delta at offset 851713 from .git/objects/pack/pack-755d3172ff230697ac8d1579d8aeb6cc0f9d83ec.pack
fatal: packed object 44ca2e9774208d6ee4f889e7bf007e475976edcb (stored in .git/objects/pack/pack-755d3172ff230697ac8d1579d8aeb6cc0f9d83ec.pack) is corrupt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/hdd2/aosp/.repo/repo/main.py", line 531, in <module>
    _Main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/hdd2/aosp/.repo/repo/main.py", line 507, in _Main
    result = repo._Run(argv) or 0
  File "/hdd2/aosp/.repo/repo/main.py", line 180, in _Run
    result = cmd.Execute(copts, cargs)
  File "/hdd2/aosp/.repo/repo/subcmds/sync.py", line 821, in Execute
    project.Sync_LocalHalf(syncbuf, force_sync=opt.force_sync)
  File "/hdd2/aosp/.repo/repo/project.py", line 1327, in Sync_LocalHalf
    self._InitWorkTree(force_sync=force_sync)
  File "/hdd2/aosp/.repo/repo/project.py", line 2486, in _InitWorkTree
    raise GitError("cannot initialize work tree")
error.GitError: cannot initialize work tree
```

I tried:

1. use repo sync -j1 - NOT OK
2. Delete the
   .repo/projects/external/jsoncpp.git and sync again - NOT OK
3. git clone 
   https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/jsoncpp.git
   somewhere else, clone is OK, copy the .git folder back and use repo
   sync --force-sync - Still NOT OK

Could anyone point out what is wrong here? Is it a server error? But I got git clone completed successfully.

Comment: Remove `./external/jsoncpp`. Enter the repo under `.repo/project-objects` and run `git fetch https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/jsoncpp.git <branch>`. The branch is specified in `.repo/manifest.xml`. Have a try and `repo sync` again.

Comment: By the way, you can use `repo --trace sync` to print more info, like the specific path of the repository in case it's not `./external/jsoncpp`.

Comment: Thanks a lot to @ElpieKay! I tried to delete the corrupt repository from .repo/project-objects .repo/projects and from source tree too, and then sync again. Then I met same error in other repositories but the process is moving on! I just have one more question, what is the content in .repo/project-objects? I never noticed it and thought all the .git folders are put in .repo/projects.

Comment: It's where objects are stored. Run `ls -al .repo/projects/foo.git` and you can see links to `.repo/project-objects/foo.git`.

Comment: @ElpieKay so I failed to fix the problem by deleting the .git folder in .repo/projects just because I only deleted the symbol links.

Comment: That's true. I found these errors quite frustrating and annoying until I learned `--trace`. =)